# How do i refresh fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a `MainActivity` and a `HomeTabs` with three tabs(A B C) all of them are `Fragment`. I set a `onRefresh` on tab C. When I trigger `onRefresh` that its view is gone. Why is that? I couldn't solve it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's my `HomeTabs`:

```
public class HomeTabs extends Fragment {
    private Context context;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    private int[] imageResId = {R.drawable.input_icon_color,
            R.drawable.note_icon_color,
            R.drawable.analytics_icon_color};

    public HomeTabs() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static HomeTabs newInstance() {
        return new HomeTabs();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_tabs, container, false);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab1)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab2)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab3)));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerDataReport);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.input_icon);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(imageResId[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(imageResId[2]);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());/

                int id = tab.getPosition();
                if (id == 0) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.input_icon);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(imageResId[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(imageResId[2]);
                }

                if (id == 1) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(imageResId[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.note_icon);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(imageResId[2]);
                }

                if (id == 2) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(imageResId[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(imageResId[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.analytics_icon);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });

        // My tab C position is 2 , when i refresh that i want to show tab C
        if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("refresh")){
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my tab C `Fragment` about refresh:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mainActivity.refreshFragment();
}
```

And the `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private Toolbar toolBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        toolBar.setTitle(R.string.myAppName);
        toolBar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.medical_history32);
        toolBar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            switchFragment(HomeTabs.newInstance());
        }


    }

    public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }



    public void setTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            new DialogHandler(this).quickDialog(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.quick),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.confirm),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.cancel),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            finish();
                        }
                    }, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    });
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    public void refreshFragment() {
        //switchFragment(HomeTabs.newInstance());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("refresh",true);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here's my tab C:

```
public class MyLineChart extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{
    private View view;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_line_chart, container, false);

        //................set my data

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702333/refresh-fragment-at-reload

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link , i have try it , it look like can be refreshed , but my tab C view is still gone when i refresh it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? what your code is trying to do is - start the `HomeTabs` fragment, load the `ViewPager` inside the `HomeTabs` fragment. Then inside C tab's `onRefresh()`, your code is trying to replace the current `HomeTabs` fragment with a new instance of `HomeTabs` fragments. You sure thats what you want ?

Comment: My structure is trigger `onRefresh` on tab C that will send the data to `HomeTabs` , when i reload HomeTabs it will show tab C not tab A.

Comment: Restarting the activity each time to refresh data is a really bad idea. Why can you just refresh your view in Tab C ? I am guessing thats where you want to show dynamic data/progress. Try setting the new data and then to refresh the view use `<view to refresh>.invalidate()`

Comment: You could also try to reload your `adaptor`: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @ZeekHuge , your guess right , but how could i use <view to refresh>.invalidate() ?

Comment: @Michal_196 . I had find some solution about `adapter.notifyDataSetChanger();` , but i do not know about how to trigger it if i set `onRefresh` on tab C in my case.

Comment: if its a simple view that you want to change, you can try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544799/listview-row-updation/41548246#41548246

Comment: @ZeekHuge I can't find my view id in tab C , so i just use `view.invalidate();`. It's not working what step i miss it ?

Comment: @徐博俊 probably you should edit the question to add code of tab C

Comment: Sure , i have update my question that add tab C.

Comment: @徐博俊 now inside `onRefresh()`, call `view.invalidate()`.
This `view` is the global variable in which you inflate the fragment layout and finally return in the `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do it.
If you are using `ViewPager` the best solution is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27422029/4157431).

You must implement (override) `getItemPosition` method in your page adapter to return (no position changed)

```
 @Override
 public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
     return POSITION_NONE;
 }
```

Then to update from anywhere, you just notify the adapter of a change

```
mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your below code for reload your fragment:

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                                   

 ft.detach(YourFragmentName.this).attach(YourFragmentName.this).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks , it can be refresh , but my problem still there that tab C view is gone when i refresh.

Answer (score 1):

first set tag to your fragment as "fragment"

```
 @Override
public void onRefresh() 
{
    Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT");
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
    fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
    fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i try your code , my tab C view is till gone when i refresh.

Comment: You just want to refresh tab C or other changes in other tabs?

Comment: I just want to refresh tab C.

Comment: first do  
` if (id == 2) {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(imageResId[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(imageResId[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.analytics_icon);
                   //setting tag is tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setTag("FRAGMENT");

                }`

Comment: if you have any data changes, make sure its written under OnViewCreated

Comment: What do you mean by this code that you reply it , and i'm sure its under OnViewCreated , bcz i can see the view when the project start first.